# Clear all fields after submit React js

Tags: reactjs

I have the following code in my React app and I need to have empty input areas after submitting the contact form. I am using `ref` and calling `handleSubmit` function on submitting the form.

```
import { useRef } from 'react';

import './Contact.css';
import emailjs from 'emailjs-com'
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const Contact = () => {

const formRef = useRef();
const [done, setDone] = useState(false);

const handleSubmit = (e) => {

    e.preventDefault();
    emailjs.sendForm(
        'service_py6v3mm',
        'template_db5q8nx',
        formRef.current,
        'mJDC1if10C25Z-TZC'
    )
        .then((result) => {
            console.log(result.text);
            setDone(true);
        }, (error) => {
            console.log(error.text);
        });

}

return (
    <div className="c">
        <div className='c-wrapper'>
            <div className='c-left'>
                <h1 className='c-title'> Let's discuss!</h1>
                <div className='c-info'>
                    <div className='c-info-item'>
                        <div className="c-info-item">
                            <img
                                src="./images/Phone.jpg"
                                alt=""
                                className="c-icon"
                            />
                            +12345678
                        </div>

                        <div className="c-info-item">
                            <img className='c-icon'
                                src="./images/Email.png" alt='Email' />
                            messimacky@gmail.com
                        </div>

                        <div className="c-info-item">
                            <img className='c-icon'
                                src="./images/Location.jpeg"
                                alt=" " />
                            Addis Ababa, Wolo Sefer, Ethio-China Road, Ethiopia
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className='c-right'>
                <p className='c-desc'> <b> Get in touch!</b>
                </p>
                <form ref={formRef} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    <input type='text' placeholder='Name' name='username' />
                    <input type='text' placeholder='Subject' name='user_subject' />
                    <input type='text' placeholder='Your email here... ' name='user_email' />
                    <textarea rows={5} placeholder='message' name='message' /> <br />
                    <button>Submit</button>
                    {done && <p> Thank you   I will contact you soon!</p>}
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}
export default Contact
```

Please assist me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind every input value to a state and empty them when you submit it. Here I add an example for the username. You can multiply it and use it.

```
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('Name');
  const submitFunctionWhichDeletes = () => {
       console.log(username);
       setUsername('');
  }
  <input ... value={username} onChange={e => setUsername(e.target.value)} ... />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const compForm = ()=>{
 const [formData,addFormData] = useState({
  username:"",
  subject:"",
  email:"",
  message:""
 })

 cosnt formSubmit =()=>{
  // make api call
  addFormData({
   username:"",
   subject:"",
   email:"",
   message:""
  })
 }   
 
 const formData = (e,filed)=>{
  const temp = {...formData}
  if (filed === "username"){
     temp.username = e.target.value
  }
  else if(filed === "subject"){
    temp.subject = e.target.value
  }
  else if(filed === "email"){
    temp.email = e.target.value
  }
  else if(filed === "message"){
    temp.message = e.target.value
  }
  addFormData(temp)
 }
 
 return(
    <>
     <input type='text' placeholder='Name' name='username' 
      value={formData.username} onChange={(e)=>formData(e,username)}/>
     <input type='text' placeholder='Subject' name='user_subject' 
      value={formData.subject}  onChange={(e)=>formData(e,subject)}/>
     <input type='text' placeholder='Your email here... ' name='user_email' 
     value={formData.email} onChange={(e)=>formData(e,email)}/>
     <textarea rows={5} placeholder='message' name='message' 
      value={formData.message} onChange={(e)=>formData(e,message)}/> 
     <button onClick = {(e)=>formSubmit()}>Submit</button>
    <>
 )
}
```